# If $x - 1/x = 1$, then find the value of $\frac{x^4 - 1/x^2}{3x^2 + 5x - 3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x - \frac 1x = 1$, then find

$$\frac{x^4 - \frac{1}{x^2}}{3x^2 + 5x - 3}$$

Was breaking my head on this.

Comment: You might recognize pretty quickly that one value for $x$ is the constant known as $\phi$ (the other being $1-\phi$).  You may be able to make use of the identity $\phi^2 = \phi +1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

As $x$ is non-zero finite,  divide the numerator & the denominator by $x$

For the numerator use  $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

since:
$$x=1+\dfrac{1}{x}$$
So:
$$x=1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+....}}}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1.6180339899...$$
That is golden number.http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html
So if:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^4 - \frac{1}{x^2}}{3x^2 + 5x - 3}.$$
Then:
$$f(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})=\dfrac{1}{16}(5\sqrt{5}-3).$$
Note:
Also:
$$x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1}+......}}.$$